# div left and right-aligned on large devices, stacked on small

Tags: css

Is there a way, without using bootstrap grid, to:

On larger devices

1. div.left left-aligned in .header-wrapper
2. div.right right-aligned in .header-wrapper

On small device

3. stack div.left and div.right on top of each other

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/klode/3ke4nj9g/)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="header-wrapper">

    <div class="left"> This is some longer text that may not fit in-line with buttons</div>
    <div class="right">
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-default">Table</a>
      <a type="button" class="btn btn-default">Charts</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p>Some content here</p>

  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="in-line">
      This would be an inline example
    </div>
    <div class="in-line">
      Divs will stack without media queries
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible without media queries?
for example using inline-block on .left .right would take care of stacking. (see inline-example in html code)

Is it possible to left/right align inline-block divs?

Comment: Look into css media queries, thats what bootstrap grid does;)

Comment: Refer this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Comment: Yes - write your own CSS & media queries. You basically wrote pseudocode for the process by writing this question.

Comment: I know I am repeating everyone here, but USE MEDIA QUERYS. You can find a tutorial at http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries. Or, you could use foundation or w3.css. You can find tutorials for those at http://www.w3schools.com/

Comment: Float the left/right columns left with a width of 50%. Use media queries to make the width 100% when you reach your small screen width.

Comment: would it be possible without media queries? for example using inline-block would take care of stacking divs when they do not fit. See edited question

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else has said, you need to use media queries.

Try this (obviously change sizes to your liking):

```
.header-wrapper { width: 100%; }
.header-wrapper > div { width: 200px; height: 50px; }
.left { background: blue; float: left; }
.right { background: red; float: right; }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px ) { 
   .right { 
      float:left; 
      clear: left; 
   } 
}
```

On screens smaller than 769px, the box with class `.right` will get `float: left;` applied to it, which will cause it to, well, float left. The `clear: left;` will cause it to stack underneath the div with class `.left`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably not groking what your'e saying, so I used a little flexbox and one media query, it looks like what *I think* you wanted. If not, let me know. BTW, I used to hate media queries because it's syntax was weird and smelled funny, but I came to the conclusion that they are here for a good reason.

http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/p7rbpuac/

### Changes

```
.header-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

 @media screen and (max-width:360px) {
   .header-wrapper {

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  }
 }
```